# How to use for loop in sql developer or oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

This is my code but while I'm running the project, it's showing error like

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROCEDURE'

I want to insert multiple records according given date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (
   IP_START_DATE           IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_END_DATE             IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_MATERIAL_TYPE        IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_BRM_LIST             IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION   IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_YARD_NO              IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_USER_ID              IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_USER_IP              IN     VARCHAR2,
   IP_RID                  IN     NUMBER,
   IP_OPERATION            IN     VARCHAR2,
   i                          OUT VARCHAR2,
   OUT_RETURN_MSG             OUT VARCHAR2,
   OUT_RETURN_CODE            OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   OUT_RETURN_MSG := '';
   OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;

   BEGIN
      IF IP_OPERATION = 'INSERT'
      THEN
         FOR i IN IP_START_DATE .. IP_END_DATE
         LOOP
            IF i <= IP_END_DATE
            THEN
               -- exit loop immediately


               INSERT INTO MST_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION (FROM_DATE,
                                                   TO_DATE,
                                                   MATERIAL_TYPE,
                                                   BRM_TYPE,
                                                   ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION,
                                                   YARD_NO,
                                                   USER_ID,
                                                   USER_IP_ADDRESS,
                                                   CREATED_DATE)
                    VALUES (IP_START_DATE,
                            IP_END_DATE,
                            IP_MATERIAL_TYPE,
                            IP_BRM_LIST,
                            IP_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION,
                            IP_YARD_NO,
                            IP_USER_ID,
                            IP_USER_IP,
                            SYSDATE);

               EXIT;
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;

      IF IP_OPERATION = 'UPDATE'
      THEN
         UPDATE MST_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION
            SET FROM_DATE = IP_START_DATE,
                TO_DATE = IP_END_DATE,
                MATERIAL_TYPE = IP_MATERIAL_TYPE,
                BRM_TYPE = IP_BRM_LIST,
                ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION = IP_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION,
                YARD_NO = IP_YARD_NO,
                LAST_UPD_TS = SYSDATE,
                LAST_UPD_UID = IP_USER_ID
          WHERE RID = IP_RID;
      -- AND VESSEL_NAME  = IP_VESSEL_NAME;
      END IF;

      OUT_RETURN_CODE := 1;
      OUT_RETURN_MSG := 'SUCCESS';
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;
         OUT_RETURN_MSG := SQLERRM;
   END;
END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: I want to insert multiple record based on the given start and end dates.

Comment: for ex:start_date=01-06-2018 and edn_date=05-06-2018, the data entry should be having for 01-06-2018 to 05-06-2018 its mean total 5 records should be insert

Comment: The error descriptions says that you have incorrect call to TEST_PROCEDURE. Please, provide the statement that you use for this procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the days between start and end and use that for your loop counter instead of trying to use the variables directly as you currently are. Even though you're passing varchar2 with dates inside them, I still trunc the casted variable for safety to guarantee a whole number.

```
select trunc(to_date(ip_end_date)) - trunc(to_date(ip_start_date))
into loop_count
from dual;
```

Change your loop to count by this

```
if loop_count > 0 then
   FOR i IN 1..loop_count loop
```

and I'm assuming you probably want to change the date for each iteration of the loop to match the day between start and end.

Comment: actually m passing variable from my project that values should be use in this if I give like ur             select trunc(to_date(ip_end_date)) - trunc(to_date(ip_start_date))
into loop_count
from dual; then its shows in valid identifier rit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using `varchar2` datatype for date datatypes. That is asking for trouble.

Now, since you want to insert records for multiple dates, you can't use for loop iterator for dates the way you do it for numbers as in `for i in 1..10`.

So, you could use a `connect by`  as a method to generate dates. Use `LEVEL` pseudocolumn to refer to the current iteration (i in the for loop)

```
INSERT INTO mst_actual_consumption (
    from_date,
    TO_DATE,  -- don't use this as a column_name as it's a function
    material_type,
    brm_type,
    actual_consumption,
    yard_no,
    user_id,
    user_ip_address,
    created_date
)
    SELECT
        ip_start_date, -- you need to use to_date if you are passing date as strings
        ip_end_date,
        ip_material_type,
        ip_brm_list,
        ip_actual_consumption,
        ip_yard_no,
        ip_user_id,
        ip_user_ip,
        SYSDATE
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        level <= ( ip_end_date - ip_start_date ); -- you need to use to_date if you are passing date as strings
```

I did not understand this part though

```
 IF i <= IP_END_DATE
            THEN
               -- exit loop immediately
```

Maybe you were trying this? If so, put it before insert and update

```
IF ip_end_date <= ip_start_date 
THEN
  RETURN;
END IF;
```

**EDIT**  you said:

> error has fixed but no records are inserting even one time also

It could be because you are not passing correct dates.As I said in the code comments, you should convert them to dates using to_date function.
For eg: if you are passing the dates as strings in the format dd-mm-yyyy, In the insert, you should use

```
level <= ( to_date(ip_end_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') - to_date(ip_start_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') )
```

Same thing has to be done in the select part of insert, if the column in table `MST_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION` is of date datatype.

```
select to_date(ip_start_date,'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date(ip_end_date,'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: yes in this case end date is greater then start date

Comment: STILL ITS GETTING ERROR LIKE PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROCEDURE'

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: WHILE I TRYING TO INSERTING DATA FROM MY PROJECT

Comment: @prudhvini : That error is not because of the insert statement. You are passing some incorrect arguments. Edit your question and show how exactly you are invoking the procedure. A sample with something of the form `exec proc1('a','b',1);` That is, you need to show us all the values you pass into the procedure. Otherwise, we won't know what "your project" is doing

Comment: :I exactly posted my procedure what I did. yet this nothing is enough

Comment: @prudhvini : You have not  understood my question. I want you to go inside the asp.net code (i knew from ur tags) and see how the procedure is being  called, what parameters are passed etc.

Comment: thnq for ur replay,error has fixed but no records are inserting even one time also

Comment: @Koushik: thnq  so much,data is insering but the problem is same date is inserting in all records it should be increament by 1 upto count

Comment: @prudhvini I've told you already to use `LEVEL` pseudocolumn as you want to refer to the current iteration  as in "i" in the for loop. So you could do  `ip_start_date + level as start_date`  ,`ip_end_date + level as end_date`   in the select part of insert. Note that you can't add level to  string,if you are passing it as string.  it has to be converted to date using to_date() as per my comments above before adding.

Comment: :yes yesterday I completed this ,its working properly and yesterday became mine because of u....thnq soo much..

Answer (score 0):

you can't loop through dates, you can probably do something like this.

```
create or replace procedure testproc(
startdate in date,
enddate in date
)
as
datediff NUMBER := enddate-startdate;
newdate date := startdate;
begin

   FOR i IN 1..datediff LOOP
   newdate := newdate+1;
   insert into temp values(newdate);
   END LOOP;
end;
```

and for your error it's because you are passing your parameters incorrectly like passing a string where argument requires integer value or you are passing incorrect number of parameters.

Comment: This may be a correct solution, but keep in  mind that a insert within a loop is always less efficient method  than a single insert

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_ADD_ACTUALCONSUMPTION (
 IP_START_DATE       IN  VARCHAR2,
    IP_END_DATE           IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_MATERIAL_TYPE       IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_BRM_LIST           IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION       IN VARCHAR2,
     IP_YARD_NO       IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_USER_ID                   IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_USER_IP                   IN VARCHAR2,
     IP_RID           IN NUMBER ,
     IP_OPERATION      IN VARCHAR2,
   --S_DATE OUT DATE,
   --E_DATE OUT DATE,
   --datediff OUT NUMBER, 
    OUT_RETURN_MSG OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_RETURN_CODE OUT NUMBER)



IS
BEGIN
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := '';
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;

 -- S_DATE :=TO_DATE(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  --  E_DATE :=TO_DATE(IP_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
   -- datediff :=E_DATE-E_DATE;

  BEGIN

IF IP_OPERATION  = 'INSERT' THEN




    INSERT INTO MST_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION
      (

      FROM_DATE,
      TO_DATE,
      MATERIAL_TYPE,
      BRM_TYPE,
      ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION,
      YARD_NO,
      USER_ID,
      USER_IP_ADDRESS,
      CREATED_DATE

      )


  select 
      TO_CHAR((to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (level-1)),'DD-MM-YYYY') ,
       TO_CHAR(to_date(IP_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YYYY') ,
       IP_MATERIAL_TYPE,
        IP_BRM_LIST,
        IP_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION,
        IP_YARD_NO,
        IP_USER_ID,
        IP_USER_IP,
        SYSDATE
         FROM
        dual
        CONNECT BY
        level <= to_date(IP_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1;

  --  to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'):=to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1;

       END IF;
            END PROC_ADD_ACTUALCONSUMPTION;
```